# Sending attachment using TIdAttachment in c++ builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy, indy10

How to send attachment using TIdyAttachment ?

How to convert this `TIdAttachment.Create(msg.MessageParts, 'c:\attach.bmp');` delphi statement to c++ builder ?
How to use this abstract class in c++ builder? Due to it's being abstract I cannot create an instance of it !!!

Comment: Really easy than it was ! Just write `TIdAttachmentFile(mess->MessageParts,"c:\\pic.jpg");`  That's done Suhrob !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `TIdAttachment` is indeed abstract (as Remy Lebeau noted in a comment). Use `TIdAttachmentFile` instead. In C++, I guess it should look like (Update: I see you already found that):

```
TIdAttachmentFile *attachment = new TIdAttachmentFile(msg->MessageParts, "C:\\attach.bmp");
```

FWIW, named constructor calls like `TMyClass.Create(args)` in Delphi are translated as `new TMyClass(args)` in C++Builder. That is why Delphi often overloads `Create`, instead of using differently named constructors like `CreateWithSpecialParams`. In Delphi, a constructor can have any name, but not in C++.

Note that in Delphi you can have a `constructor Create(Integer)` and a `constructor CreateEx(Integer)` and they are distinguishable. This is not translatable to C++Builder, since **both** translate to `MyClass(int)`, so doing that should be avoided if the Delphi programmer wants his or her class to be usable in C++Builder.

Comment: actually, in Indy 10, `TIdAttachment` *is* an abstract class.  You have to use `TIdAttachmentFile` instead.

Comment: Correct syntax is msg->MessageParts